# Find m∠UTR if m∠UTR = 7y - 5 and m∠USR = 3y + 15.

Tags: geometry

Find $∠UTR$ if $∠UTR = 7y - 5$ and $∠USR = 3y + 15$. 
Diagram in this link!    https://postimg.org/image/nmpf8hl8h/   thank you!

Comment: I just need help and guidance through the question to have a better understanding.. I don't need the exact answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: page 1]

Angles on the same arc denoted by "a" are same.

So we have,

$7y - 5 = 3y + 15$

$7y - 3y = 15 + 5$

$4y = 20$

$y = 5$

So $\angle MTR = 7(5) - 5 = 30$

Answer (score 1):

Angle UTR and angle USR cover the same arc of the circle (namely, arc UR), so they must be equal.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**

$$\angle UTR=\angle USR = 2\cdot \overparen{RU} $$

Doing that you can find $y$ and then calculate $\angle UTR$.